# Fade in on mouse movement

Tags: javascript, mouseevent, fade

How do I fade in div content on first mouse movement, like on google.com, using JavaScript? I don't want it to fade out again.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**Code: ([See it in action](http://jsbin.com/ituwa3/7/))**

```
// attach event handler
document.body.onmousemove = function(){
  fadeIn( this, 1000 );      // 1000ms -> 1s
  this.onmousemove = null; // remove to only fade in once!
};

// sets the opacity of an element (x-browser)
function setOpacity( obj, value ) {
  if ( obj ) {
    obj.style.opacity = value / 100;
    obj.style.filter  = 'alpha(opacity=' + value + ')';
    obj.style.zoom    = 1;
  }
}

// makes an element to fade in
function fadeIn( dom, interval, delay ) {

      interval  = interval || 1000;
      delay     = delay    || 10;

  var opacity   = 0,
      start     = Number(new Date()),
      op_per_ms =  100 / interval;

  if ( typeof dom === "string" ) {
    dom = document.getElementById( dom );
  }

  function step() {

    var now     = Number(new Date()),
        elapsed = now - start;
        opacity = elapsed * op_per_ms;

    setOpacity( dom, opacity );

    if ( elapsed < interval )
      setTimeout( step, delay );
    else
      setOpacity( dom, 100 );
  }

  setTimeout( step, delay );
};
```

**Note:** the fade function could've been smaller, but in this form you can reuse it easily for any element and duration. Have fun!

Comment: well i see no jQuery tag, it's kinda obvious. for me at least... :)

Comment: This doesn't fade in on mousemovement. It just fades in .

Comment: it is because of jsbin. I checked it locally and it works. Google uses similar to this, so it should work. Or point exactly to the part where it fails. Nothing? Thought so...

Comment: well you can feed the fadeIn function whatever element you want. it's totally up to you. The code is still good btw...

Comment: Something tells me the fact that you've edited this like fifty bajillion times tripped some ancient if-then-else condition which converted your question into a wiki.

Comment: Probably something to do with people adding one character to their answer in an attempt to bump the question and get a little more rep.

Answer (score 4):

If you use jquery and want it to fade in like google you could do something like this

```
$('body').mousemove(function() {
  $('#content').fadeIn();
});
```

Comment: Might want to also disconnect the handler after it's fired, so it doesn't continue getting fired again.

Comment: Agreed with Matt Briggs and the Galactic Cowboy - http://jsbin.com/uvene3 here this is in action

Comment: You should use `$().one('mousemove',function(){})` rather than just binding to mousemove, since it is intended to only be triggered once.

Answer (score 3):

You can create a fade in effect for the body just like Google with the following code. Please take into consideration this will have similar functionality to Google. You can apply this technique to any element with the proper event handler.

```
var fps = 24;
var mpf = 1000 / fps;

function fadeIn(ele, mils) {
    // ele: id of document to change.
    // mils: number of mils for the tansition.
    var whole = 0;
    var milsCount = 0;
    var subRatio = 1 / (mils / mpf);

    while (milsCount <= mils) {
        setTimeout('setOpacity("' + ele + '", ' + whole + ')', milsCount);
        whole += subRatio;
        milsCount += mpf;
    }

    // removes the event handler.
    document.getElementById(ele).onmouseover = "";
}

function setOpacity(ele, value) {
    ele = document.getElementById(ele);

    // Set both accepted values. They will ignore the one they do not need.
    ele.style.opacity = value;
    ele.style.filter = "alpha(opacity=" + (value * 100) + ")";
}
```

You will want to add the event handler to the body of the document in whatever fashion you normally do. Be sure to modify the fadeIn function to pull information from the target/srcElement if you decide to use an attachment method that does not accept arguments. Or you can hard code desired values and objects into the function:

**Inline:**

```
<body id="theBody" onmouseover="fadeIn('theBody', 1500)">
```

**DOM Level 0:**

```
document.getElementByTagName("body")[0].onmouseover = function(){ code here };
document.getElementByTagName("body")[0].onmouseover = fadeIn;
```

**DOM Level 2:**

```
document.getElementByTagName("body")[0].addEventListener("mouseover", fadeIn);
document.getElementByTagName("body")[0].attachEvent('onclick', fadeIn);
```

You will also want to set up a css rule for the body element to make sure that it is not visible when the page loads:

```
body {
    opacity: 0;
    filter:alpha(opacity=0);
}
```

I have checked this code to work correctly on IE8, Chrome, Safari, FireFox, and Opera. Good luck.

Comment: Might want to show how to attach it to the element (body?) as well.

Comment: The update I made should help people. Thank you for showing the flaw in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Using CSS3 animations, for whoever supports it at this point.

```
body {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 0.3s linear;
}
```

In the above example, whenever we change the `opacity` on the body, it will do a fade effect lasting `0.3` seconds linearly. Attach it to mousemove for one time only.

```
document.body.onmousemove = function() {
    this.style.opacity = 1;
    this.onmousemove = null;
};
```

See google.com revamped [here](http://jsbin.com/uzanu3/2) :) Chrome and Safari only.

Answer (score -1):

I would recommend using a javascript library such as http://jquery.com/.

Using jquery, if you wanted to fade in a div with id "content", you could write the following javascript code...

```
$(document).mousemove(function() {
    $("#content").fadeIn();
});
```

Comment: where is the code to attach it to the mousemove event of the document when the dom finishes loading?