# how to create google effect?

Tags: javascript, jquery, effect

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Fade in on mouse movement (like on google.com)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3168207/fade-in-on-mouse-movement-like-on-google-com)

i wonder how to create google effect on my home page.

i want exacty same effect. explain me in detail to use it on my home page.

Comment: google have so many effects ....which effect are u talking abt ?
elaborate plz

Comment: are you talking about google homepage fadein effect?

Comment: http://www.google.com/ - I guess this one is the one. Btw: I'm quite surprised this question got +2.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3168207/fade-in-on-mouse-movement-like-on-google-com

Answer (score 2):

user JQUERY  `animate or fedin` with `document mouseover` event will help you

[Creating a Mouseover Fade Effect with jQuery](http://bavotasan.com/tutorials/creating-a-jquery-mouseover-fade-effect/)

Fore example :

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
$(document).ready(function(){
$("img.a").hover(
function() {
$(this).stop().animate({"opacity": "0"}, "slow");
},
function() {
$(this).stop().animate({"opacity": "1"}, "slow");
});

});
</script>
```

Comment: somebody, please correct the typos :-)

Answer (score 2):

You can use [jQuery](http://jquery.com):

```
$('.controlsContainer').fadeIn();
```

This code will fade in all elements with a class of `controlsContainer`.

Answer (score 1):

check and learn contents in this link **http://docs.jquery.com/Main_Page**. its the documentation of jquery. try learn it your self, while doing it if you face problems you query it.

And also this link **http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/15-resources-to-get-you-started-with-jquery-from-scratch/**.

this link points to video tutorials of jquery for beginerrs **http://net.tutsplus.com/articles/web-roundups/jquery-for-absolute-beginners-video-series/**

this will help you